# Modified algorithm for building a Heap

Tags: algorithm, heap

I am quite new to programming and I am trying to understand a certain problem regarding heap sort. In a book I'm reading, there is a modified algorithm for building a max heap, which is:

```
BuildHeap(A)
    A.heap-size = 1
    for i = 2 to A.length
        Heap-Insert(A, A[i])
```

So from my understanding, this algorithm takes in an array and defines the size of the heap to be 1 and then iterates from 2 to the total length of the array and then inserts the value into the heap.

But how would this build a max heap? If I had an array of [4, 7, 2, 3, 9, 1], then wouldn't the algorithm start at value 2 and then simply add all the values from the A[2] to A.length to the heap without actually building a max heap?

I do not understand how the `heap-size = 1` does anything in the algorithm other than restrict the total size of the heap. I am confused as to how you would build a max heap.

From what it states in the book, the normal max heap works by first inserting every array value into a heap, and then starting at the A/2 place, then working backwards and swapping values that are larger than the current value being assessed by calling `Max-Heapify`.

So how would this max heap work since there is no `Max-Heapify(A, largest)` call, but instead there is simply a `heap-insert(A, A[i])`?

Comment: Heap-insert increases the size of the heap by one (A.length += 1) and ensures that the heap property is maintained by inserting the new element in the right place.

Comment: If it increases the size of the heap by 1, then does it not just add the next value in the array to the heap without actually making it a max heap? So if the array was used above, wouldn't the array first start with the value 2, and then increase the heap by 1 and add 3 below the 2 in the heap?

Comment: In pseudo code, it is often the habit to use 1-based indexing so A[2] is the second element in A, so that is the 7.

Comment: @trincot Correct me if I am wrong, but the algorithm first looks  at the 2nd through last entry of the array and simply adds the largest? Does Heap-insert implicitly select that largest element of the array? I am simply trying to understand where in this small code does the actual selection of the largest element of the array happen.

Comment: Well, the Heap-Insert routine does all the hard work of bubbling up the rightmost value in its correct position. Note that your title is misleading: this is not heapsort, but building a heap.

Comment: @trincot That is how I understood the original max-heap within the book. This max-heap does not include a max-heapify function or a function that searches for the right most element. Unless... does the for loop implicitly search for the largest element from the 2nd entry to the last entry of the array and then add it using heap-insert?

Comment: I added an answer, I hope it clarifies things for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this question is not about heap sort, which is just one of the *applications* for a heap. You are asking about the heap *construction*.

The pseudo code you presented is indeed an alternative (and less efficient) way of building a heap, and this would actually be the algorithm that many would come up with when they wouldn't have known about the standard algorithm of Floyd.

So taking a look at the code:

```
BuildHeap(A)
    A.heap-size = 1
    for i = 2 to A.length
        Heap-Insert(A, A[i])
```

Most of the logic of this algorithm is berried inside the `Heap-Insert` function, which is not just a simple "append" to an array: it does much more than that. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Insert) describes that hidden algorithm as follows:

> 1. Add the element to the bottom level of the heap at the leftmost open space.
> 2. Compare the added element with its parent; if they are in the correct order, stop.
> 3. If not, swap the element with its parent and return to the previous step.

You write in your question:

> there is no Max-Heapify(A, largest)

Indeed, it would be too simple if you already *knew* what the largest value was before using the heap. You need to *first* insert a value (any value) in a heap, and let the heap do its magic (inside `Heap-Insert`) to make sure that the largest value ends up in the first (top) position in the array `A`, i.e. in `A[1]`.

The first step of the quoted algorithm is thus important: `Heap-Insert` expects the new value to be inserted *at the end*.

Let's work through the example [4, 7, 2, 3, 9, 1], and let's put a pipe symbol to indicate the end of the heap. At the start, the heap size is 1, so we have:

```
4 | 7   2   3   9   1
```

Let's also represent a more visually appealing binary tree at the right side -- it just has a root element:

```
4 | 7   2   3   9   1                  4
```

Then we call `Heap-Insert(A, A[2])`, which is `Heap-Insert(A, 7)`. The implementation of `Heap-Insert` will increase the size of the heap, and put that value in the last slot, so we get:

```
4   7 | 2   3   9   1                  4
                                      /
                                     7
```

`Heap-Insert` has not finished yet -- this was just the first step it performs. Now it "bubbles up" that 7 following steps 2 and 3 of that quoted algorithm, and so we get:

```
7   4 | 2   3   9   1                   7
                                       /
                                      4
```

At the second iteration of the pseudo code loop, we call `Heap-Insert(A, 2)`, so `Heap-Insert` performs its first step:

```
7   4   2 | 3   9   1                   7
                                       / \
                                      4   2
```

...and finds out that nothing needs to change when performing step 2 and 3.

We continue inserting 3:

```
7   4   2   3 | 9   1                   7
                                       / \
                                      4   2
                                     /
                                    3
```

...and again nothing needs to change as 3 is less than 4 (remember that `A[2]` is the parent of `A[4]`.

We continue inserting 9:

```
7   4   2   3   9 | 1                   7
                                       / \
                                      4   2
                                     / \
                                    3   9
```

And here 9 > 4, and also 9 > 7, so `Heap-Insert` will further modify `A` to this:

```
9   7   2   3   4 | 1                   9
                                       / \
                                      7   2
                                     / \
                                    3   4
```

One more to go:

```
9   7   2   3   4   1                   9
                                      /   \
                                     7     2
                                    / \   /
                                   3   4 1
```

And `Heap-Insert` has nothing more to do as 1 < 2.

Comment: Thank you, that was a very helpful!